# DHT11 sensor with adafruit_DHT library keeps giving None reading

Tags: raspbian, dht22

I am trying to get readings from a DHT11 sensor (temperature and humidity). I installed the library like so:

```
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT.git
cd Adafruit_Python_DHT

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-openssl

sudo python setup.py install
```

Then I tested it out by trying (in python) to `import Adafruit_DHT` and this worked.

Then I tried running `t, h = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(11,3)` and it keeps returning None, None. My DHT11 sensor comes on a board with a +, -, and out wires and I have a raspberry pi B+ I put the plus into a power pin (1), the minus into a ground pin (6), and the out wire into a gpio pin (3).

Anyone have any ideas why it is not working?

EDIT: I tried, as per joan's suggestion, used different software and the sensor works however I still have not been able to get any python code to work.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you try some other software which will work provided you have connected the DHT11 correctly.

Try my [DHTXXD](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_DHTXXD) software.  It requires the pigpio daemon to be running (e.g. sudo pigpiod).

The DHT11 (and other DHT models) require accurate timing of pulses a few tens of microseconds long.  pigpio is one way of getting accurate times.

Comment: Hi @joan, thanks for the reply! I tried your software and it works. I need python code (not c code) so I guess I will try [this](https://github.com/joan2937/pigpio/tree/master/EXAMPLES/Python/DHT11_SENSOR) example and hopefully that will work

Comment: Trying that python example did not work. It outputs 0,0 for temp and humidity readings with every try. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is more than a year late, but in case somebody visits this question, here is what I had success with:

1. I am using Velleman's VMA311, which is a DHT11 with a 10kohm pull-up resistor
2. I am using Pi 3 B+ - the 1-Wire pin is 7 (GPIO4) and you have to enable it (the easiest is thru the UI or thru terminal: `sudo raspi-config` select the "5. Interfacing Options", "P7 1-Wire" and then "<Yes>", finally restart)
3. I connected the sensor's:

   - "-" to GND (pin 6)
   - "+" to 3V3 (pin 1)
   - "S" (signal) to GPIO4 (pin 7)
4. Finally save the following script to a file and execute: `python temp-hum.py`

```
    import sys
    import Adafruit_DHT

    sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT11
    pin = 4

    while True:
        humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
        print 'Temp: {0:0.1f} C  Humidity: {1:0.1f} %'.format(temperature, humidity)
```

Useful information about the 1-wire configuration can be found at [pinout.xyz](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/1_wire#)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the pin number you feed into read_retry is the GPIO pin number not the board pin number. For example, on my pi, GPIO 17 corresponds to board number 11.